# external HDD raid box - works for admin user, does not work for non-admin user

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk

Total apple/macOS noob here, please be patient.

I have a colleague with a macBook Pro running the latest macOS. For this user I have bought an external HDD box housing two HDDs which run in a raid 1 config. This is purely for archival purposes.

We now face the "interesting" behaviour, that for admin-users the box will show up, mount and is usable.

If we log in as the normal, non-admin user, we don't see anything happening. The HDDs stir a bit, when the box is connected, however the external harddrive never shows up in Finder.

---

Are there any specific permissions, that we need to give the non-admin user? I really would like to avoid enabling admin-rights for the normal user account, since this goes against any advice relating to computer security.

I suspect, some of the magic of the external raid box is limited somewhere along the process by missing rights, since it works for admin-users and the box also works when connected to a Windows PC.